# Update all rows where "NULL" as string needs to be updated to a DB NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to change all occurrences of a certain value within SQL regardless of column?

I have a table with ~200 columns which was imported from a text file. The NULL values came through as the string value 'NULL' and occur in most columns within the table. Is there a way to convert those values to true NULL values? I would like to avoid using UPDATE on each individual column is possible.

Comment: Fix the file and re-import.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: The files were created through a python script. It's 72 csv files and I haven't been able to import NaN values from python to SQL successfully.

Answer (score 2):

A single update may not be too painful:

```
update t
    set col1 = nullif(col1, 'NULL'),
        col2 = nullif(col2, 'NULL'),
        . . .;
```

You can generate the code in SQL or a spreadsheet by querying `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`(or similar) for string columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic sql to build out the update script...

DECLARE @update_sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

```
SELECT 
    @update_sql = CONCAT(@update_sql, N',
    mt.', c.name, N' = NULLIF(mt.', c.name, N', ''NULL'')')    
FROM
    sys.columns c
WHERE
    c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.MyTable')
    AND c.collation_name IS NOT NULL; -- easy way to make sure you're only looking at columns that can hold test data. 

SET @update_sql = CONCAT(N'
UPDATE mt SET',
STUFF(@update_sql, 1, 1, ''), N'
FROM 
    dbo.MyTable mt;')

PRINT(@update_sql);
```

You'll end up with output formatted like the following...

```
UPDATE mt SET
    mt.column_9 = NULLIF(mt.column_9, 'NULL'),
    mt.column_10 = NULLIF(mt.column_10, 'NULL'),
    mt.column_11 = NULLIF(mt.column_11, 'NULL'),
    mt.column_14 = NULLIF(mt.column_14, 'NULL'),
...
    mt.column_165 = NULLIF(mt.column_165, 'NULL'),
    mt.column_166 = NULLIF(mt.column_166, 'NULL'),
    mt.column_167 = NULLIF(mt.column_167, 'NULL'),
    mt.column_168 = NULLIF(mt.column_168, 'NULL')
FROM 
dbo.MyTable mt;
```

Note... The PRINT command is limited to 8000 characters of ASCII and 4000 characters of unicode. So, if you notice that the output script is being truncated, post back, I have a "long print" procedure that get around that limitation.

Answer (score 0):

use the [merge statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and set null for all matching rows which is fasters and efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this without doing an update on each individual column.

There are shortcuts to writing such an update, like right-click>script as... or dynamic sql, but so far that's not what you've asked.